# skpaymentqueue canmakepayments memory leak checks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I run `Instrument` to check `Leaks` in my app. It got 1 new leaks `[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]` every time start up even no code for payment is called.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same leak, it's leaking very little but it's still a problem. 
I'm using AdMob and game center leaderboards. What are you using in your app ?

Comment: It might be a bug http://www.openradar.me/27421128

Comment: What do you see when you use the Xcode 8 memory graph debugger?  http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/

Comment: Observed same issue @timestamped date of this comment

Comment: @3366784 same issue, were you able to solve?

Comment: issue still exists May 20, 2018...anyone solve this?

Answer (score 2):

According to this date, `SKPaymentQueue's` `CanMakePayments` has memory leak and you can not do anything with it because it's `Apple's` one. There are lots of tickets opened in Apple's with the same issue. It exists on `iOS 10` too. Hope they will fix this issue. ref: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22312

Comment: The issue you mentioned has nothing to do with memory leaks.