# Instruments show leak in [AVAudioSessionPortDescription initWithPortType:] (Xcode 8.2.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, avfoundation

I am developing an app using ARC. When  profiling my app in instruments for memory leaks it shows leaks at the following Library/Frame:

Responsible Library: AVFAudio

Responsible Frame: -[AVAudioSessionPortDescription initWithPortType:]

[image]
Note: Second memory leak at [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] is already reported in this post: [skpaymentqueue canmakepayments memory leak checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051914/skpaymentqueue-canmakepayments-memory-leak-checks)

Comment: I can see these leaks only on simulator (ios 11). Same code (AVAudioSessionPortDescription initWithPortType:) produces no leaks in Instruments on a real device (iOS 11).